# AWS Lambda for Secrets Manager Password Rotation giving Errors for RDS(postgres)

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager, aws-lambda-layers

I have downloaded the python function from https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/blob/master/SecretsManagerRDSPostgreSQLRotationSingleUser/lambda_function.py. Also, I am using Terraform to deploy ( Python Runtime is 3.9 as suggested). However, After deployment I am getting the following errors in CloudWatch Logs

`[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'function': No module named 'pg' Traceback (most recent call last):`

I also tried to create a Lambda layer but it did not help.

Appreciate any help !!

Answer (score 0):

That Lambda function is apparently dependent on [the PyGreSQL library](http://www.pygresql.org/). I don't see anything in the documentation for that function about that, but that's obviously what it is using. I'm surprised those sample functions don't include a `requirments.txt` file for their dependencies. There are [some](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/issues/68) [open](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/issues/52) [issues](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/issues/35) in that GitHub repository related to this.

You would have to package that function's code along with the PyGreSQL library and any other dependencies into a .zip file, and modify your Terraform code to deploy the .zip file to Lambda.

Comment: Thanks,  I  am thinking of using pg8000 and try to replace pg/pgdb since adding a layer for wrangler is simple. Question -- has anyone used pg8000 to solve this problem?

Comment: If you are asking if anyone else has used pg8000 to connect to an RDS PostgreSQL server from AWS Lambda, the answer is yes, I have done that. It works fine.

Comment: I should have been more specific. I have also used pg8000 but I was looking for an answer if someone else has converted the secrets manager rotation lambda to use pg8000 ? If not, will try myself in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pg8000.
Here is the lambda to rotate the password:

```
# Copyright 2018 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT-0

import boto3
import json
import logging
import os
import pg8000

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """Secrets Manager RDS PostgreSQL Handler
    This handler uses the single-user rotation scheme to rotate an RDS PostgreSQL user credential. This rotation
    scheme logs into the database as the user and rotates the user's own password, immediately invalidating the
    user's previous password.
    The Secret SecretString is expected to be a JSON string with the following format:
    {
        'engine': <required: must be set to 'postgres'>,
        'host': <required: instance host name>,
        'username': <required: username>,
        'password': <required: password>,
        'dbname': <optional: database name, default to 'postgres'>,
        'port': <optional: if not specified, default port 5432 will be used>
    }
    Args:
        event (dict): Lambda dictionary of event parameters. These keys must include the following:
            - SecretId: The secret ARN or identifier
            - ClientRequestToken: The ClientRequestToken of the secret version
            - Step: The rotation step (one of createSecret, setSecret, testSecret, or finishSecret)
        context (LambdaContext): The Lambda runtime information
    Raises:
        ResourceNotFoundException: If the secret with the specified arn and stage does not exist
        ValueError: If the secret is not properly configured for rotation
        KeyError: If the secret json does not contain the expected keys
    """
    arn = event['SecretId']
    token = event['ClientRequestToken']
    step = event['Step']

    # Setup the client
    # secret manager endpoint https://secretsmanager.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    service_client = boto3.client('secretsmanager', 'us-west-2')

    # Make sure the version is staged correctly
    metadata = service_client.describe_secret(SecretId=arn)
    if "RotationEnabled" in metadata and not metadata['RotationEnabled']:
        logger.error("Secret %s is not enabled for rotation" % arn)
        raise ValueError("Secret %s is not enabled for rotation" % arn)
    versions = metadata['VersionIdsToStages']
    if token not in versions:
        logger.error("Secret version %s has no stage for rotation of secret %s." % (token, arn))
        raise ValueError("Secret version %s has no stage for rotation of secret %s." % (token, arn))
    if "AWSCURRENT" in versions[token]:
        logger.info("Secret version %s already set as AWSCURRENT for secret %s." % (token, arn))
        return
    elif "AWSPENDING" not in versions[token]:
        logger.error("Secret version %s not set as AWSPENDING for rotation of secret %s." % (token, arn))
        raise ValueError("Secret version %s not set as AWSPENDING for rotation of secret %s." % (token, arn))

    # Call the appropriate step
    if step == "createSecret":
        create_secret(service_client, arn, token)

    elif step == "setSecret":
        set_secret(service_client, arn, token)

    elif step == "testSecret":
        test_secret(service_client, arn, token)

    elif step == "finishSecret":
        finish_secret(service_client, arn, token)

    else:
        logger.error("lambda_handler: Invalid step parameter %s for secret %s" % (step, arn))
        raise ValueError("Invalid step parameter %s for secret %s" % (step, arn))


def create_secret(service_client, arn, token):
    """Generate a new secret
    This method first checks for the existence of a secret for the passed in token. If one does not exist, it will generate a
    new secret and put it with the passed in token.
    Args:
        service_client (client): The secrets manager service client
        arn (string): The secret ARN or other identifier
        token (string): The ClientRequestToken associated with the secret version
    Raises:
        ValueError: If the current secret is not valid JSON
        KeyError: If the secret json does not contain the expected keys
    """
    # Make sure the current secret exists
    current_dict = get_secret_dict(service_client, arn, "AWSCURRENT")

    # Now try to get the secret version, if that fails, put a new secret
    try:
        get_secret_dict(service_client, arn, "AWSPENDING", token)
        logger.info("createSecret: Successfully retrieved secret for %s." % arn)
    except service_client.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException:
        # Get exclude characters from environment variable
        exclude_characters = os.environ['EXCLUDE_CHARACTERS'] if 'EXCLUDE_CHARACTERS' in os.environ else ':/@"\'\\'
        # Generate a random password
        passwd = service_client.get_random_password(ExcludeCharacters=exclude_characters)
        current_dict['password'] = passwd['RandomPassword']

        # Put the secret
        service_client.put_secret_value(SecretId=arn, ClientRequestToken=token, SecretString=json.dumps(current_dict), VersionStages=['AWSPENDING'])
        logger.info("createSecret: Successfully put secret for ARN %s and version %s." % (arn, token))


def set_secret(service_client, arn, token):
    """Set the pending secret in the database
    This method tries to login to the database with the AWSPENDING secret and returns on success. If that fails, it
    tries to login with the AWSCURRENT and AWSPREVIOUS secrets. If either one succeeds, it sets the AWSPENDING password
    as the user password in the database. Else, it throws a ValueError.
    Args:
        service_client (client): The secrets manager service client
        arn (string): The secret ARN or other identifier
        token (string): The ClientRequestToken associated with the secret version
    Raises:
        ResourceNotFoundException: If the secret with the specified arn and stage does not exist
        ValueError: If the secret is not valid JSON or valid credentials are found to login to the database
        KeyError: If the secret json does not contain the expected keys
    """
    # First try to login with the pending secret, if it succeeds, return
    pending_dict = get_secret_dict(service_client, arn, "AWSPENDING", token)
    conn = get_connection(pending_dict)
    if conn:
        conn.close()
        logger.info("setSecret: AWSPENDING secret is already set as password in PostgreSQL DB for secret arn %s." % arn)
        return

    # Now try the current password
    conn = get_connection(get_secret_dict(service_client, arn, "AWSCURRENT"))
    if not conn:
        # If both current and pending do not work, try previous
        try:
            conn = get_connection(get_secret_dict(service_client, arn, "AWSPREVIOUS"))
        except service_client.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException:
            conn = None

    # If we still don't have a connection, raise a ValueError
    if not conn:
        logger.error("setSecret: Unable to log into database with previous, current, or pending secret of secret arn %s" % arn)
        raise ValueError("Unable to log into database with previous, current, or pending secret of secret arn %s" % arn)

    # Now set the password to the pending password
    try:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute("ALTER USER " + pending_dict['username'] + " WITH PASSWORD '" + pending_dict['password'] + "'")
            conn.commit()
            logger.info("setSecret: Successfully set password for user %s in PostgreSQL DB for secret arn %s." % (pending_dict['username'], arn))
    finally:
        conn.close()


def test_secret(service_client, arn, token):
    """Test the pending secret against the database
    This method tries to log into the database with the secrets staged with AWSPENDING and runs
    a permissions check to ensure the user has the corrrect permissions.
    Args:
        service_client (client): The secrets manager service client
        arn (string): The secret ARN or other identifier
        token (string): The ClientRequestToken associated with the secret version
    Raises:
        ResourceNotFoundException: If the secret with the specified arn and stage does not exist
        ValueError: If the secret is not valid JSON or valid credentials are found to login to the database
        KeyError: If the secret json does not contain the expected keys
    """
    # Try to login with the pending secret, if it succeeds, return
    conn = get_connection(get_secret_dict(service_client, arn, "AWSPENDING", token))
    if conn:
        # This is where the lambda will validate the user's permissions. Uncomment/modify the below lines to
        # tailor these validations to your needs
        try:
            with conn.cursor() as cur:
                cur.execute("SELECT NOW()")
                conn.commit()
        finally:
            conn.close()

        logger.info("testSecret: Successfully signed into PostgreSQL DB with AWSPENDING secret in %s." % arn)
        return
    else:
        logger.error("testSecret: Unable to log into database with pending secret of secret ARN %s" % arn)
        raise ValueError("Unable to log into database with pending secret of secret ARN %s" % arn)


def finish_secret(service_client, arn, token):
    """Finish the rotation by marking the pending secret as current
    This method finishes the secret rotation by staging the secret staged AWSPENDING with the AWSCURRENT stage.
    Args:
        service_client (client): The secrets manager service client
        arn (string): The secret ARN or other identifier
        token (string): The ClientRequestToken associated with the secret version
    """
    # First describe the secret to get the current version
    metadata = service_client.describe_secret(SecretId=arn)
    current_version = None
    for version in metadata["VersionIdsToStages"]:
        if "AWSCURRENT" in metadata["VersionIdsToStages"][version]:
            if version == token:
                # The correct version is already marked as current, return
                logger.info("finishSecret: Version %s already marked as AWSCURRENT for %s" % (version, arn))
                return
            current_version = version
            break

    # Finalize by staging the secret version current
    service_client.update_secret_version_stage(SecretId=arn, VersionStage="AWSCURRENT", MoveToVersionId=token, RemoveFromVersionId=current_version)
    logger.info("finishSecret: Successfully set AWSCURRENT stage to version %s for secret %s." % (token, arn))


def get_connection(secret_dict):
    """Gets a connection to PostgreSQL DB from a secret dictionary
    This helper function tries to connect to the database grabbing connection info
    from the secret dictionary. If successful, it returns the connection, else None
    Args:
        secret_dict (dict): The Secret Dictionary
    Returns:
        Connection: The psycopg2 object if successful. None otherwise
    Raises:
        KeyError: If the secret json does not contain the expected keys
    """
    # Parse and validate the secret JSON string
    port = int(secret_dict['port']) if 'port' in secret_dict else 5432
    dbname = secret_dict['dbname'] if 'dbname' in secret_dict else "postgres"

    # Try to obtain a connection to the db
    try:
        logger.info("host: " + secret_dict['host'])
        conn = pg8000.connect(
            host=secret_dict['host'],
            user=secret_dict['username'],
            password=secret_dict['password'],
            database=dbname,
            port=port
        )
        return conn
    except pg8000.Error:
        return None


def get_secret_dict(service_client, arn, stage, token=None):
    """Gets the secret dictionary corresponding for the secret arn, stage, and token
    This helper function gets credentials for the arn and stage passed in and returns the dictionary by parsing the JSON string
    Args:
        service_client (client): The secrets manager service client
        arn (string): The secret ARN or other identifier
        token (string): The ClientRequestToken associated with the secret version, or None if no validation is desired
        stage (string): The stage identifying the secret version
    Returns:
        SecretDictionary: Secret dictionary
    Raises:
        ResourceNotFoundException: If the secret with the specified arn and stage does not exist
        ValueError: If the secret is not valid JSON
    """
    required_fields = ['host', 'username', 'password']

    # Only do VersionId validation against the stage if a token is passed in
    if token:
        secret = service_client.get_secret_value(SecretId=arn, VersionId=token, VersionStage=stage)
    else:
        secret = service_client.get_secret_value(SecretId=arn, VersionStage=stage)
    plaintext = secret['SecretString']
    secret_dict = json.loads(plaintext)

    # Run validations against the secret
    # if 'engine' not in secret_dict or secret_dict['engine'] != 'postgres':
    #     raise KeyError("Database engine must be set to 'postgres' in order to use this rotation lambda")
    # for field in required_fields:
    #     if field not in secret_dict:
    #         raise KeyError("%s key is missing from secret JSON" % field)

    # Parse and return the secret JSON string
    return secret_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

You might receive this error if you're running an earlier Lambda function that was automatically upgraded from Python 3.7 to a newer version of Python. To resolve change the Lambda function version back to Python 3.7, and redeploy the Lambda function.

Ref: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/secrets-manager-lambda-rotation